# 208 volt watt meter for servers

Tags: power

Anyone ought to be familiar with a 120v power meter, or watt meter, such as the *kill-a-watt* brand of watt meter like this

[image]

They are easily found online... amazon... less than $20.

Is there one that will do 208 volt single phase and be able to be used in a server room where rack servers run on 208 volt power using those female type 208v power cords and the PDU's that are in a server rack?

I would like to use some kind of watt meter that will measure wattage/amperage on 208v for just one server running, to understand the power draw of a given server when it is on but idle vs when software is crunching on it.

And i don't need a convenient all in one meter like in the pic.  I am ok with building a box and doing any wiring to make a safe and temporary connection to make a amp/watt measurement.  So any kind of amperage or watt [panel] meter I am ok with if it is not overly expensive and reasonably accurate in the 20 watt to 5000 watt range at 208 volt.

Here is what a PDU (power distribution unit) within a server rack looks like.

[image]

The power cable from this PDU to the wall, has an L6-30P *plug* where the receptacle on the wall is an L6-30R.

Where I want to measure is after the PDU, coming from one of its eleven **C14** receptacles.  I have plenty of C14 power cords I can cut a few up.

https://www.webberelectronics.com/info/iec-chart
The actual socket might be C18/C19/C20, I don't know and it kinda doesn't matter because I have plenty of those power cords that I can use to wire up an amperage/watt meter.  I am basically just looking for any kind of panel meter that will measure amperage/wattage at 208 volt.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbvtttVtIxQ

Comment: Amazon has a number of devices, such as https://www.amazon.com/Pass-through-Rail-Volts-energy-meter/dp/B07D43BHSY/ref=sr_1_8 . Have you looked?

Comment: had found EKM-25IDS on amazon around $100, but finding more hits now on such devices

Comment: also Baomain DDS238-4 @ $27

Comment: I may also do a current transformer setup  such as `CrocSee AC 80-260V 100A CRS-022B` for $20